# Angular4 routing parent > child : Hook that runs when navigating back to parent?

Tags: angular, angular4-router

Say I have two components and their respective routes:

- ParentComponent `/parent`
- ChildComponent `/parent/child`

I'm looking for a way to trigger a method on the parent as the router is told to navigate to "../" from the child view.

I look for an equivalent of Ionic's hook "viewDidAppear":

- it's not initialized as it was still in the nav stack
- it's just getting foreground again and some refresh should occur

Thanks for your attention,

Comment: You could use an emitter and then react to it in the parent component: 
    @Output() pleaseNavigate = new EventEmitter(); and then just pleaseNavigate.emit('whatever'); and react to it in the parent with (pleaseNavigate)="foo($event)". Example: http://learnangular2.com/outputs/

Comment: you can also make use of shred services or make use of router outlet events

Comment: @RahulSingh this is exactly what I needed for this case! Thanks

Comment: you can subscribe to router events pretty much anywhere you can inject the router, they have navstart / navend events, see the angular docs for more.

Answer (score 4):

Are they parent and child *components* or parent and child *routes*?

When they are parent and child *components*, then the child component's selector is defined within the parent component's template. When that is the case, you can use @Output to communicate between the parent and the child.

If they are parent and child *routes*, then the child component's template appears in the parent component's router outlet. In that case you can watch the route parameters with code like this:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(param => console.log(param));
```

Add this to the ngOnInit of the parent component to start watching the events. Then, instead of logging as I've shown here, you can trigger the desired method.

Comment: Hi DeborahK, thanks it's interresting. The use of router outlet events were a better fit to my particular case but your info will certianly come in handy in the days to come.